# Rails 4 ActiveRecord, how run Where AND Between

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to run a query with Rails 4 but I don't know how to do it.

I have it in 2 times but I need to do it on the same line.

```
@events = Event.scoped
@events = Event.where(:club_id => params[:club_id])
@events = Event.between(params['start'],params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])
```

So actually only the scoped and the between work, I need to insert the name in the between but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `Model.scoped` is deprecated in `Rails4` .Use `Model.all` instead.

Comment: Ok thanks but the problem is that my BETWEEN destroy my WHERE condition. When I remove the between I have my event with club_id but not between start and end. And if I let it like that I have all events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should do:

```
@events = Event.scoped.where(:club_id => params[:club_id])
@events = @events.between(params['start'],params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])
```

Comment: Than you can do `@events = @events.where("time between #{params['start']} and #{params['end']}") if (params['start'] && params['end'])` in the second line. it will surely work.

Comment: Ok your solution was good I just had some trouble with my model I think.